# Checking prime number with a for loop

Tags: java

Need to a run a code that iterates through numbers from 2 up to - number, and gives a boolean about the input number in isPrime method.
I keep getting 'true' regardless of what I input, 7 , 28, etc.

```
// Import statement:
import java.util.ArrayList;
class PrimeDirective {
    // Add your methods here:
    public boolean isPrime(int number) {
        int prime = 0;
        int checkPrime = number % 1;
        
        if (number == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (number < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        PrimeDirective pd = new PrimeDirective();
        int[] numbers = { 6, 29, 28, 33, 11, 100, 101, 43, 89 };
        System.out.println(pd.isPrime(7));
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: read about proper Java code indentation. You should put your { braces at the end of a line, and be consistent about using always the same indentation. Such things matter. They make your code easy to read, or hard to read.

Comment: Also: please do proper research before posting a question. It is impossible that you would be the first one to ask a question on isPrime().

Answer (score 1):

First, just eliminate 2 by dividing by it first.  This then allows you to check for divisibility by just odd numbers.

```
public boolean isPrime(int v) {
   if (v == 1 || v%2 == 0) {
       return false;
   }
   // then you just need to check for divisibility up to the
   // square root of the number.
   int max = (int)Math.sqrt(v) + 1;
   for (int i = 3; i <= max; i+=2) {
      if (v % i == 0) {
           return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Im not quite clear on the math here, why the square root?

Comment: Consider some number like 19.  If 19 were divisible by 2  to give `q`, then 19 would also be divisible by `q` to give 2.  If by 3 to give `s` then also by `s` to give 3.  So future divisions have already been caught.  The point at which one can stop looking is that point when `k * k = 19`.  or the next number above the square root.  For 19 that would be  5.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is if any `number > sqrt(n)` divides `n` then there must be a `number <  sqrt(n)` that also divides `n`. So only dividing by numbers up to the `sqrt(n)` is all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to check if a number is not prime. Your code would look like so:

```
for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)    
  if (number % i == 0 && number != i)
      return false;

return true;
```

Comment: Too much unnecessary checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your Result and Optimise code if you check for only half of the number because Idealy we only need to check for square root of the number.

```
public boolean isPrime(int number){
 for(int i=2;i<number/2;i++)
     if(number%i==0)
          return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What if `number = 1`? Your method will return `true` which is wrong as `1` is not a prime number. Also, there is no need to check up to `number/2`. Checking up to sqrt of number (`i<=Math.sqrt(number)`) is enough. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test